# Why Are My Sprites Not Drawing To The Screen In Pygame

Tags: python, windows, pygame

I have recently been trying to make a Snake game in python.  The program shows no errors at all, yet the sprites do not draw when I run the program.  I've tried to run the program in Python instead on in Visual Studio Code, I tried to change the name of Variables, I have reviewed the code many times as well.  Please Help.

```
import pygame
import sys
import random

#Snake
class snake(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 1
        self.positions = [((Screen_Width / 2), (Screen_Height / 2))]
        self.direction = random.choice([Up, Down, Left, Right])
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)

    def head_position(self):
        return self.positions[0]

    def turn(self,point):
        if self.length > 1 and (point[0] * -1, point[1] * -1) == self.direction:
            return
        else:
            self.direction = point

    def move(self):
        cur = self.head_position()
        x, y = self.direction
        new = (((cur[0] + (x * Grid_Size)) % Screen_Width), (cur[1] + (y * Grid_Size)) % Screen_Height)
        if len(self.positions) >2 and new in self.positions[2:]:
            self.reset()
        else:
            self.positions.insert(0, new)
            if len(self.positions) > self.length:
                self.positions.pop()

    def reset(self):
        self.length = 1
        self.positions = [((Screen_Width / 2), (Screen_Height / 2))]
        self.direction = random.choice([Up, Down, Left, Right])

    def draw(self, surface):
        for p in self.positions:
            r = pygame.Rect((p[0], p[1]), (Grid_Size, Grid_Size))
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, r)
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, (93, 216, 228), r, 1)

    def handle_keys(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    self.turn(Up)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    self.turn(Down)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.turn(Left)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.turn(Right)


#Apple
class apple(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = (0, 0)
        self.color = (192, 7, 7)
        self.randomize_position()

    def randomize_position(self):
        self.position = (random.randint(0, Grid_Width - 1) * Grid_Size, random.randint(0, Grid_Height -1) * Grid_Size)

    def draw(self, surface):
        r = pygame.Rect((self.position[0], self.position[1]), (Grid_Size, Grid_Size))
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, r)
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (9, 196, 46), r, 1)

#Draw The Grid
def draw_grid(surface):
    for y in range(0, int(Grid_Height)):
        for x in range(0, int(Grid_Width)):
            if (x + y) % 2 == 0:
                r = pygame.Rect((x*Grid_Size, y*Grid_Size), (Grid_Size, Grid_Size))
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (9, 196, 46), r)
            else:
                rr = pygame.Rect((x*Grid_Size, y*Grid_Size), (Grid_Size, Grid_Size))
                pygame.draw.rect(surface, (7, 138, 33), rr)


#Screen
Screen_Width = 500
Screen_Height = 500

Grid_Size = 20
Grid_Width = Screen_Height / Grid_Size
Grid_Height = Screen_Width / Grid_Size

#Movement
Up = (0, -1)
Down = (0, 1)
Left = (-1, 0)
Right = (1, 0)

#Main Game Loop
def Main():
    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Screen_Width, Screen_Height), 0, 32)

    surface = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    surface = surface.convert()
    draw_grid(surface)

    the_snake = snake()
    food = apple()

    my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 16)

    score = 0

    #Handling Events.
    while (True):
        clock.tick(10)
        the_snake.handle_keys()
        draw_grid(surface)
        the_snake.move()
        if the_snake.head_position() == food.position:
            snake.length += 1
            score += 1
            food.randomize_position()
        screen.blit(surface, (0, 0))
        text = my_font.render("Score {0}".format(score), 1, (0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(text, (5, 10))
        pygame.display.update()

#Call On The Main Function.
Main()
```

Comment: Where is the call to the draw method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dear programmer
I think the error in your code is that you defined the function to draw the snake and the apple but you forgot to call them so you just need to add this code to the main loop and it will run fine

```
the_snake.draw(surface)
food.draw(surface)
```

Comment: I think you might be right but which line do I put it in exactly, because nothing changed when I put it in the Event Handler at the end of it.  I'm sorry, I'm a beginner so I don't want to waste your time.

Comment: Don't worry dear programmer you will never wast my time because I love helping...
You just need to add those two lines after you draw the grid

Comment: It works now, (tysm) but there is now one other issue, I can't pickup the apple (food).

Comment: The problem is that when you create the snake its position is not centred with the grid so the snake is never in the grid making it impossible to be at the same position as the food. One solution for this is making the size of the sreen propotional to the grid size, for example the gird has a size of 20 so you can make the screen be 600x600 that is a multiple of 20. And in line 130 (when you increase the snake's lenght) you wrote 'snake' instead of 'the_snake':
`the_snake.length += 1`

Comment: Thank you man!  It all works now!  You're a Legend!  :D

Comment: Thank YOU. You put a smile in my mouth...